# Unique key with not null values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array like this one:

```
const es = [
  ['A', 'A1'], // first A key
  ['B', null],
  ['C', null],
  ['A', null], // second A key
  ['B', null],
  ['C', null],
  ['D', 'D2']
]
```

what I want is:

```
const res = {
  A: 'A1',
  B: null,
  C: null,
  D: 'D2'
}
```

So I want an object with unique key where if there are duplicated keys (like `A`, `B`, `C`) with different values, the value of the key is the not null value.

To get `res` I can do:

```
const res = Object.fromEntries(flatten(es))
```

But in this case, `res` is:

```
res = {
    A: null,
    B: null,
    C: null
  }
```

I think because `Object.fromEntries` "makes a `set`" and the second `A` key replace the first one.
So, which is the best way to do what I want?

Comment: What's `flatten`?

Comment: What if there are duplicate keys where neither value is null? Take first, last, or won't happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

You need to set new value only if:

- value is empty `null` or `undefined`
- Both the values exists and are valid

Idea is to assign first value and replace with latest non-empty value.

```js
const es = [
  ['A', 'A1'], // first A key
  ['B', null],
  ['C', null],
  ['A', null], // second A key
  ['B', null],
  ['C', null],
  ['D', 'D2']
]

const result = es.reduce((acc, [ key, value ]) => {  
  if (acc[ key ] == null || !!acc[ key ] && !!value) acc[key] = value;
  return acc
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const es = [
  ['A', 'A1'],
  ['B', null],
  ['C', null],
  ['A', null],
  ['B', null],
  ['C', null],
  ['D', 'D2']
]

const reduced = es.reduce((accumulator, currentItem) => {
  const [key, value] = currentItem
  accumulator[key] = accumulator[key] || value
  return accumulator
}, {})

console.log(reduced)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use a loop, checking to see if the object doesn't have the property or it does but the value is `null`:

```
const obj = {};
for (const [key, value] of es) {
    if (!(key in obj) || obj[key] === null) {
        obj[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const es = [
  ['A', 'A1'], // first A key
  ['B', null],
  ['C', null],
  ['A', null], // second A key
  ['B', null],
  ['C', null],
  ['D', 'D2']
];
const obj = {};
for (const [key, value] of es) {
    if (!(key in obj) || obj[key] === null) {
        obj[key] = value;
    }
}
console.log(obj);
```

Re [CertainPerformance's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59930050/uniq-key-with-not-null-values/59930109#comment105982092_59930050), the above takes the first, so if you want one of the other options you'll need to adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple `forEach` loop to iterate over the inner arrays and update existing object properties if they are still `null`, but there is a new value:

```js
const es = [
  ['A', 'A1'], // first A key
  ['B', null],
  ['C', null],
  ['A', null], // second A key
  ['B', null],
  ['C', null],
  ['D', 'D2']
]

let obj = {};
es.forEach(arr => {
  // check if object key does not exist yet; or has null value and can be updated with non-null value
  if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(arr[0]) || (obj[arr[0]] === null && arr[1] !== null)) {
    obj[arr[0]] = arr[1];
  }
});
console.info(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use combination of map and set. this is the easiest way get distinct from an arry of objects

```js
var es =[
  ['A', 'A1'], // first A key
  ['B', null],
  ['C', null],
  ['A', null], // second A key
  ['B', null],
  ['C', null],
  ['D', 'D2']
]
var obj={};
var dist = [...new Set(es.map(function(x){
if(!obj[x[0]])
obj[x[0]] = x[1];
return obj;
}))][0]
console.log(dist);
```